# How to retrieve/display multi columns single row from database to different html tags

Tags: php, html

OK so what I'm am trying to do is retrieve multiple columns of data from a single row in mysql database and basically place the data of the different columns into multiple places on my html code such as in "p" and "td" tags to display on webpage.

I have successfully been able to display the "description"(description is the name of 1 of the database columns) inside the "p" tags using PHP but I don't know how to display any other columns of the database into other html tags such as the "td" tags. There is probably going to be a total of roughly 10 columns of text in database I want to display in the webpage but again where it's displaying is in various html tags and not a table which is what I keep finding when researching and tired of banging my head on the desk. There is a small example below. I'm learning as I go so any help would be great. Thank you!

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Parts;";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
?>

<div class="description">
<h3>Descrption</h3>
  <p>
    <?php 
    if($resultCheck > 0) {
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row['Description'];
      }
    } 
    ?>
  </p>
</div>

<td>
  <?php 
  if($resultCheck > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      echo $row["Material"];
    }
  } 
  ?>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this   

     
    
        <?php
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM Parts;";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                
                      if($resultCheck > 0) {
                      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        ?>
                
                <div class="description">
                <h3>Descrption</h3>
                  <p>
                    <?php 
                    
                        echo $row['Description'];
                     
                    ?>
                  </p>
                </div>
                
                <td>
                  <?php 
                  
                      echo $row["Material"];
        
                  ?>
                </td>
        <?php 
    
        }
    }
        ?>
```

Comment: OMG! Thank you it worked. I checked it with the other columns I was talking about too and worked for those as well. I did try a slight variation of what you had placed but I obviously had something wrong with my code prior to posting my original question. Thanks again

Comment: Welcome bro, am glad that I answered your question and it worked for you, maybe you should flag it as answer, to help other users who get into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

My preference is to fetch all rows first, rather then fetching rows while rendering html, otherwise if there is an error fetching rows, it becomes mixed in with your html

I also recommend using htmlentities() to escape any html data (assuming that description or material does not already include valid html

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Parts;";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

?>

<div class="description">
<h3>Descrption</h3>
  <p>
    <?php 
      foreach ($rows as $row) {
        echo htmlentities($row['Description']);
      }
    ?>
  </p>
</div>

<td>
  <?php 
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
      echo htmlentities($row["Material"]);
    } 
  ?>
</td>
```

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation, I'm not entirely sure about the htmlentities though like no knowledge of it, yet, in my database its just words, sentences or some numbers that are being returned to the webpage. Eventually there will probably be hundreds of entries in the msql database, it's basically products and info about the products that need to be accessed to be placed onto the website when called from a button to the product page, if that makes sense.

Comment: If you are sure your text won't contain > or < then you don't need to use it. I always use it for user editable text.

Comment: Okay gotcha, well thanks again for the info and I will keep this in mind.